# How many HBase servers should I have per Hadoop server?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata

I have a system which will feed smaller image files which are stored in an HBase table which uses hadoop for the file system.

I have 2 instances of hadoop currently and 1 instance of HBase, but my question is what should the ratio here be?  SHould I have 1 hadoop per hbase server or does it really matter?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is it depends. 
It depends how much data you have, cpu utilization of regionserver and various other factors. You need to do some Proof of concepts to realise the sizing of your hadoop and hbase cluster. Variability of using hadoop and hbase depends on use-cases.

As a matter of fact, I have recently seen a setup where hadoop and hbase cluster totally decoupled. In the setup hbase cluster remotely uses hadoop to R/W on HDFS.